# Why is this value in my Base class property wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a BaseController that all of my Controllers derive from.

```
    public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
        public static User CurrentUser;
        public BaseApiController()
        {

        }

        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);

            var request = controllerContext.Request;
            if (request.Headers.Authorization != null && request.Headers.Authorization.Scheme.Equals("bearer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                CurrentUser = Helpers.JwtAuthentication.UserToken(request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter);
            }
        }

        protected User ActiveUser
        {
            get
            {
                return CurrentUser;
            }
        }
    }
```

I make use of the `ActiveUser.Id` object through out a lot of my controllers. There are thousands of users making use of the system.

Our logs are showing us that the incorrect user is being saved against logs they did not perform.

Why would the ActiveUser property be incorrect?

Comment: A single, `static`, application-wide value for "current user" seems like a very bad idea.  How have you confirmed that multiple simultaneous users of the application aren't simply over-writing this value?  I'd bet the answer here is simply... "Don't do that".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because CurrentUser is declared static. That means the value is shared between all the objects that have the BaseApiController type. In asp.net each request is processed on a separate thread by a separate object, however because they all share the same CurrentUser variable the value will be whatever the last request to run Initialize set it to. Thus the CurrentUser will leak across requests.